# Android HTTP request wierd 404 not found issue

Tags: android, http, http-status-code-404

In my application, I am trying to hit a URL which I do using the following code

```
  try {
    url = new URL(serverURL);

    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    int timeout = 30000;
    httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(timeout);

    httpURLConnection.connect();

    String httpResponseMessage = httpURLConnection.getResponseMessage();
    responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Response code "+responseCode);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The (confidential) URL when opened through browser (on computer as well as on phone), works perfectly and the response is as expected. But when I hit the same URL via the above piece of code, it gives me response code 404 (NOT FOUND). Can anybody tell me what the issue can be?
(Sorry, can not post the URL since is highly confidential.)

Comment: Have you tried a different URL with the same code?

Comment: Yes for other URLS, the response code is 200 as expected.

Comment: So can you open that URL in the phone's browser? (In case it's a firewall config issue)

Comment: What? Which URL? The one which is working fine? Or the other one?
I want to do some action according to the response code, when I hit the same URL through the browser and through the app, the behaviour is different. The response codes I get are 200 and 404 respectively.

Comment: I mean the not working URL. Are you testing it using the phone's browser or your computer's browser?

Comment: On both the browsers it works absolutely fine. Sorry for the trouble, I should have cleared it in the question itself. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved :)

```
      try {

            url = new URL(serverURL);

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, url+"");
            HttpGet method= new HttpGet(new URI(serverURL));
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(serverURL));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
            responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Response code response "+response);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Response responseCode "+responseCode);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Did you figure out what caused the error in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have the [android.permission.INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) declared in your `AndroidManifext.xml`?

Comment: Yes. I can do other internet related activity too.

Comment: if the permission were not granted in the Manifest, the would not even be a response code

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't even need following two lines in your code.

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(new URI(serverURL));
```

One HttpGet is enough and you don't need it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this matters but I had the exact problem.

I was doing some explicity port 80 stuff and removing this line made it work:

```
HttpHost host = new HttpHost(targetHost, 80, "http");
```